# When creating a Visual Studio extension, how can you tell if the mouse if hovering over a comment?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions

I'm attempting to write an extension for Visual Studio 2019 Community Edition. My goal is that when you hover over a keyword in a comment, it pops up a tooltip. I know how to pop up a tooltip (thanks to [this sample](https://github.com/microsoft/VSSDK-Extensibility-Samples/tree/master/AsyncQuickInfo)). I didn't find an easy way to identify the word I was hovering over, but I brute-force parsed it. So that part's working, as well. The last piece that I need is to know if that word that I'm hovering over is in a comment or not.

```cs
// Hovering of THIS_KEYWORD should pop up a tooltip.
var _ = "Hovering over THIS_KEYWORD should not pop up a tooltip.";
```

I've looked at [ITextView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.itextview?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) and [SnapshotSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.snapshotspan?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) and what feels like a million other interfaces in that namespace, but the best I've been able to find is [ITextSnapshot.ContentType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.itextsnapshot.contenttype?view=visualstudiosdk-2019). That only tells me that I'm working in `CSharp`. (The documentation on this part of MSDN is sorely lacking.)

I could try to brute-force this one, too... looking for `//` at the beginning of the line or for a prior `/*` without a prior `*/`, but then I'd have to extend it for each different programming language. (`--` for SQL, `'` for VB, what does Fortran use?) The editor itself knows what a comment is; it color-codes them. How can I know?

Answer (score 1):

[IClassifier.GetClassificationSpans](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.text.classification.iclassifier.getclassificationspans?view=visualstudiosdk-2019) returns text classifications. You can then check if one of the classifications is a comment.